# Oracle patch conflict

Tags: oracle, windows-server

I'm attempting to apply patch 23530402 to Oracle 11.2.0.4 with OPatch 11.2.0.3.15 on a 64-bit Windows 2008 server.  Our Tenable security software indicates this is one of two patches that must be applied to resolve a finding.  Patch 23530402 is the prerequisite for the second patch.

There are two patches already applied:  22839608 and 22839614.

OPatch bombs out with the following error in the log:

> Conflicts/Supersets for each patch are:
>
> Patch : 23530402
>
> Conflict with 22839614
>
> Conflict details:
>
> D:\dbApplicationX\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\rdbms\admin\oracle.sym
> D:\dbApplicationX\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oracle.exe
>
> Bug Superset of 22839608 Super set bugs are: 17551261, 18226143, 18689530, etc.

The log then recommends using the MOS Patch Conflict Checker at https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchConflictCheck to resolve the conflict.  Unfortunately, the Conflict Checker utility states that "patch(es) on Windows platform are not supported for conflict analysis".  (You have to float your mouse over the button long enough to activate the tool tip containing this information; otherwise it gives no indication of what's wrong with it.)

The log also has this advice:

> OUI-67073:UtilSession failed: Please rebuild the superset patch
> [23530402] to make sure it supersedes all the relevant patch(es)
> [22839608,22839614].
>
> The rebuild patch should contain bug fix
> [17551261, 18226143, 18689530, 18904062, etc.].

It wants me to rebuild an Oracle patch?  How?  Is this an appropriate time to use opatch apply -force?  Thanks for any help you can provide.  Definitely not an Oracle master here, so it's appreciated.

Comment: Open a ticket with Oracle support. This is way too localised for anyone here to really help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

22839608 is the prerequisite patch for 22839614. If you try to replace it with a newer one (23530402), the prerequisite will not be fullfiled for 22839614 -> conflict.

I would try to rollback the conflicting patch (160419 JavaVM) and install the newer version of it:

```
opatch rollback -id 22839614

sqlplus / as sysdba
startup upgrade
@?/sqlpatch/22839614/postdeinstall.sql
shutdown immediate
startup
```

Now try to apply 23530402, and after that, apply 23515277 (160719 JavaVM, you did not mention this, but that is the newer version of 22839614).

Comment: You are right--23515277 is the other patch Tenable is asking for.  Let me give your directions a try on our test system and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I was able to install both patches on the test system by following your advice, which was far more helpful than the cryptic log messages...I have noticed a new problem when I connect to the database with Oracle SqlDeveloper (Status: Failure-Test failed: thinJndiLdapConnectTimeout).  Not sure if this is a side-effect of the patches or a separate but concurrent issue.  The database is operating, however, and so is the web site connected to it, so thanks again.